# How to find the next biggest number in a binary search tree

Tags: c, algorithm, data-structures, big-o, binary-search-tree

I have this function that I want to return the smallest node that is greater than or equal to the given node, or NULL if there is no such node.

I have written this pseudocode

```
// searches for the smallest node greater than or equal to a given node
static Node doTreeNext(Tree t, Node n, Node target) {
    // no record greater
    if (n == NULL) {
        return NULL;
    }

    if (n > target) {
        return doTreenNext(t, n->left, target);
    } else if (n <= target) {
        return doTreenNext(t, n->right, target);
    } 
}
```

The issue is if I had a tree like the following

https://i.stack.imgur.com/U8pEI.png

Where the expected output for when the target node is 12, is 13. The function currently will return NULL, since

13 > 12 (searches left)
11 < 12 (searches right, which is NULL)

My question is how do I stop it at 13?

Comment: So.. you want the upper-bound of the given value (tucked into a node, for some reason), sometimes also called an *exclusive ceiling*? Unrelated, whomever convinced you hiding pointer types in typedef aliases (e.g. `typedef struct Node *Node;` in the code you didn't post) somehow brings clarity to your code, they're sorely mistaken. It makes the code *harder* to read; not easier. Also, `t` is never used anywhere, effectively an unreferenced argument, so it begs asking, why is it an argument at all?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Threaded_binary_tree

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Every time you hit a node that is larger your target value, you have a potential candidate for an answer, which should be taken unless the recursive answer call doesn't result in null.

What you should have something like the following pseudocode:

```
if (n > target) {
      candidate = search(n->left);
      if (candidate is null) {
           return n;
      } 
      else {
           return candidate;
      }
}
else {
     return search(n->right);
}
```

Comment: this makes so much sense thank you!

Comment: also notice that your original function never returns anything other than null. Each return statement is either a recursive call or "return null".

Comment: yeah, it was incomplete because I was confused about the logic but this cleared it up. legend!